# Is there a way to detect when value is set via jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few readonly textfields and a datepicker written in plain old javascript. The problem is I need to detect when the text is being set, but since that same js is used everywhere across the site, I can't really put code(like `something.trigger('change')`) inside the js file. Is there any other way to detect the change without modifying the calendar js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well onchange does not fire if the value is changed with JavaScript which stinks in some cases.

There were [mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Mutation_events), but they were deprecated and the future there will be Mutation Observers, but they will not be fully supported for a long time. So what can you do in the mean time?

You can use a timer to check the element.

```
function addValueListener(elemId, callback) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(elemId);
    var lastValue = elem.value;
    window.setInterval( function() {   
       var value = elem.value;
        if (value !== lastValue) {
            callback();   
            lastValue = value;
        }
    },10);
}
```

written as jQuery:

```
function addValueListener(elemId, callback) {
    var elem = $(elemId);
    var lastValue = elem.val();
    window.setInterval( function() {   
        var value = elem.val();
        if (value !== lastValue) {
            callback();   
            lastValue = value;
        }
    },10);
}
```

Running Example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/85Vu7/)

Comment: Mutation events were never well supported. Not sure about using `setInterval` though, surely the OP can use a click event on an ancestor element of the calendar and run the function from that (perhaps with a slight delay to give the calendar time to update the value)? If the user isn't clicking on the calendar, the value isn't changing.

Comment: @RobG so the user can set the event when the calendar is activated and do not reset it when the value has changed. Seems logical to me.